# How to load the static html in the browser pointing to folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, directory

My folder structure,

```
public---|
         |-index.html
         |-static-|
                  |-static.html
```

When I run the project as localhost:4000,it points to public folder and index.html is loaded but now I want to load staic.html when 
I type localhost:4000/static but still index.html is loaded can anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: type this way localhost:4000/static/static.html or rename static.html to index.html

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround for Apache**

Change your Apache configuration.

Add this configuration element to your VHost :

```
<Directory /static/>
    DirectoryIndex static.html
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your angular-routing cases, this can happen if you have "when" clause pointing to "/" for template.

```js
.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "/"
    })
```